# How to keep jquery featherlight popup hidden and manually open it

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm using the featherlight plugin (https://github.com/noelboss/featherlight) for a pop-up on my website. The pop-up contains HTML - no images, etc.

What I want to do is trigger the pop-up when someone loads the page.

So I created my content like this:

```
<div id="myPopup">
    <p>content...</p>
</div>
```

And I trigger it on page load like this:

```
$(function() {
    $.featherlight('#myPopup');
});
```

This works, in terms of making the pop-up appear. But it also means that the content inside `#myPopup` is visible within the page.

I tried hiding it with CSS like this:

```
<div id="myPopup" style="display: none;">
```

This hides the pop-up within the page, but means it's not visible when the featherlight pop-up opens.

How is it possible to do this so that the content is visible inside the pop-up, but hidden on the rest of the page?

`#myPopup` has to be within the `<body>` tag, because otherwise there's no way to bring it into the page - I don't want a solution which uses ajax to call an external page, for example.

Comment: Are you including featherlight's css also? `<link href="//cdn.rawgit.com/noelboss/featherlight/1.7.9/release/featherlight.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: Yes I have installed it all correctly.

Comment: @CBroe Not sure if that's a sarcastic comment. There's a bounty for it, as clearly I cannot get it working. So if you can post a fully working example then obviously there might be something worthwhile in it for you...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Featherlight simply clones the element to display inside the modal (which is why you should rather not be using IDs anywhere inside there - I'll replace it with a class), so you can get this to work by simply making the clone inside the modal's sub-tree visible again:

```
<style>
.myPopup { display: none; }
.featherlight-content .myPopup { display: block; }
</style>

<div class="myPopup">
    <p>content...</p>
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    $.featherlight('.myPopup');
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/12zr882q/

Comment: Awesome, thanks. It says I can't award the bounty for 23 hours. But I'm happy with this so will when I can.